# Node render page inside route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to reload a page with a certain message after checking some conditions inside a post request in Node JS.
My code is :

```
app.post('/audio_upload', function(req,res){
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
        form.multiples = false

        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            if(err) throw new Error(err)

        var track = files.upl.path 
        probe(track, function(err, probeData) {
             var lengthInSeconds = probeData['streams'][0]['duration']
             if(lengthInSeconds > 600) {
                var mainMessage = 'Error'
                res.render('main.ejs',{
                    message: req.flash(mainMessage),
                })

             }
             return
        });
```

The app reaches the condition `if(lengthInSeconds.600` but it doesn't render the main page. 
Can you please help me ?

Comment: It'll only render if the condition evaluates true.

Comment: it is true, but it's not rendering nothing, that's the problem :)

Comment: @AlexandruSerban you have mentioned that your it reaches till `if(lengthInSeconds.600`, but did u checked if your `if` condition is `true` ?

Comment: Try putting a `console.log` inside the condition scope to confirm. Try just `res.send('testing..')`, in case your view ('main.ejs') could be the problem. Also you're missing an awful lot of semicolons; sometimes missing them can produce strange behavior.

Comment: i'm not using semicolons at all, that's not an issue, i had a log inside my condition, also tried res.send ..it's not working :(

Comment: @Kelsadita Yes, my condition is true

Comment: No, I meant *not* using them could create an issue. You should always use semicolons where they belong.

Comment: How are you accessing the route `/audio_upload`?

Comment: Try putting `res.render` in a [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). Also try posting more code, maybe problem lies somewhere else. The `app.post` function you've posted cuts off after `probe` end, is there anything else you're doing inside the route, like calling `next`?

Comment: the intention is not to perform any more operations if this condition is true, the rest of the code should be executed only if the condition is false

Comment: `probe` seems to be an Async function. Regardless of what happens ***inside*** it (or rather, inside the anonymous function which you've passed it as the second argument) the flow of execution **will** go past it. You should put everything inside it if you want it to be affected by that condition.

Comment: i've everything inside the if else condition now, i've added the else. The problem seems to be at rendering the page, i don't know why, but it still doesn't render the page

Comment: i also tried res.redirect('/page') with a different page & a different route for it but it still doesn't work

Comment: do you know any solution on refreshing the page with a flash message if the condition is true ?